# React AG Grid: Memory piling up, even after grid unmounted

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

We used React AG Grid to render out a dashboard to show about ~150k rows (we use pagination). There's a feature to fetch for a completely new set of data, if it has been generated, but I recently ran into the issue where after 3-4 refreshes, the app crashes caused by *out of memory* error. I started investigating and seen that there seems to be leaks whenever we set the state to be it an empty array or the new payload we received.

I was able to reproduce in a new project, deployed here: https://effervescent-madeleine-b55caa.netlify.app/

If you hit the button and render the grid -> Populate rowData -> Empty rowData -> Debug tools -> Memory Tab, the memory is still being taken up

If you then destroy the grid, memory still isn't being released.

Comment: set the rowData to null or undefined? maybe then it will be garbage collected!

Comment: @NarenMurali I tried already and it doesn’t seem to have an effect

Comment: This problem is still relevant. Tell us, did you manage to solve it?